# Why isn't the useEffect hook being called when serving a React app with 'serve'?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on a React app where I am using the useEffect hook to fetch data from an API endpoint when the page first loads. Here is an example of my code:

```
useEffect(() => async () => {
   const items = await getItems(); // api call
   setItems(items);
}, []);
```

This works perfectly fine when I run the app with `npm start` in the development server, but when I try to serve the app using serve (by running `npm run build` followed by `serve -s build`), the `useEffect` hook is not being called.

What is the reason for that? And what is the correct way to fetch data when the page first reloads in a React app served with serve?

Thank you.

I'd expect the react app would function the same as it function with the node server.

Comment: Possible typo? That useEffect is defining a function, but not calling it inside the Effect

Comment: In the server, API calls are slow. Please check whether the response is getting data after the component is rendered.

Comment: Thanks. I don't believe it's a typo, because it does work with the node server. Regarding the second option of getting data after the component is rendered, if that the situation, how it's usually solved? is there some "correct way" to do that?

Comment: Are you hydrating your app? `useEffect` does not run on the server, which I think is what's happening when using `npm serve`

Comment: Actually really new to React and didn't know until now about "hydrating the app". I'll make my research about that now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to install `cors` in your node server

```js
app.use(cors())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).